# Rails return to same page after form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, redirect

In Rails, is there a short-cut to setting up a form so that the app is redirected back to the page containing the form upon success?

For example, suppose I have a site with a resource `https://myApp.com/data_display/2023-06-05` that contains a form.

The form is submitted to a different route (e.g., `https://myApp.com/handle_form`). After the form submission is processed, I want the app to return to `https://myApp.com/data_display/2023-06-05`.  I can do that by placing `2023-06-05` as a hidden field in the form, building the URL in the form handler, and doing a redirect.

Is there a better, more "rails-like" way of handling this situation (e.g., without the hidden parameter)?

Comment: Do you want it to redirect or render? For [redirect](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html) seems `redirect_back_or_to` should work. For render we would need to understand your controller better.